# How to ignore file or path in golang lint tool in vscode

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I am using Go in vscode, but the lint marks me that I have problems in third party packages.

It is possible to put a rule to ignore the src folder, for example?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems shown on your screenshot are related to `go vet` and not to `golint`

To pass an absolute path to `go tool vet` or `golint` do as follows:

1. Go to `File > Preferences > Settings` or hit `Ctrl+,`
2. Add the file or directory path to `"go.vetFlags"` or `"go.lintFlags"`, i.e. `"go.vetFlags": ["/path/to/file"]`

For some reason, on go extension 0.6.78 it adds a `.` argument to the `go tool vet` (you can inspect it on OUTPUT tab in VSCode):

```
Finished running tool: /usr/local/go/bin/go tool vet /path/to/file .
```

which causes PROBLEMS tab to display messages regarding all the files in your workspace.

NOTE: also make sure `go.lintOnSave` and `go.vetOnSave` are set to `package` and not `workspace`. You can turn off any of them by setting it to `off`